# Duplicate RowReduce

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithm

Writing:

```
Ab = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 2}, 
      {4, 3, 5, 6, 3}, 
      {1, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 
      {9, 1, 2, 3, 2}};
RowReduce[Ab]
```

I get:

> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1/16}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 0, 3/16}, 
>   {0, 0, 1, 0, -(5/16)}, 
>   {0, 0,0, 1, 5/8}}

Now my goal is to duplicate this with just *for loops* and *if-else conditional checks*.

Unfortunately, writing:

```
n = 4;

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
        If[i != j,
           For[k = 1, k <= n + 1, k++,
               Ab[[j, k]] = Ab[[j, k]] - Ab[[i, k]] * Ab[[j, i]] / Ab[[i, i]]
              ]
          ]
       ]
   ]

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
    Ab[[i, n + 1]] = Ab[[i, n + 1]] / Ab[[i, i]]; 
    Ab[[i, i]] = 1
   ]

Ab
```

I get:

> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 2}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 0, 1}, 
>   {0, 0, 1, 0, 4/7}, 
>   {0, 0, 0, 1, 2/3}}

and I don't understand how to correct. Could anyone give me a hand? Thank you!

---

**Edit**:

writing:

```
n = 4;

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
        If[i != j,
           coef = Ab[[j, i]] / Ab[[i, i]];
           For[k = 1, k <= n + 1, k++,
               Ab[[j, k]] = Ab[[j, k]] - Ab[[i, k]] * coef
              ]
          ]
       ]
   ]

For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
    Ab[[i, n + 1]] = Ab[[i, n + 1]] / Ab[[i, i]]; 
    Ab[[i, i]] = 1
   ]

Ab
```

I get:

> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1/16}, 
>   {0, 1, 0, 0, 3/16}, 
>   {0, 0, 1, 0, -(5/16)}, 
>   {0, 0,0, 1, 5/8}}

which is what is desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following piece of code to the innermost loop allows you to inspect intermediate results:

```
Echo[{"i=" <> ToString@i, "j=" <> ToString@j, "k=" <> ToString@k, Ab}]
```

You will then notice that your "row operations" currently only change *one element* of each row, rather than the *entire row*, as they should.

You should change your element-wise code:

```
Ab[[j, k]] = Ab[[j, k]] - Ab[[i, k]] * Ab[[j, i]] / Ab[[i, i]]
```

to this row-wise treatment:

```
Ab[[j]] = Ab[[j]] - Ab[[i]]*Ab[[j, i]] / Ab[[i, i]]
```

With that change, you can reproduce the result of `RowReduce`.